# match string after the last colon

Tags: javascript, regex

i have the following string

> foo: 21, bar: 11

where foo and bar are not constants, so I'm trying to match all the digits after the last **":"**(colon) character.

```
const myString = 'foo: 21, bar: 11'
myString.match(/\d+/g).shift().join() -> 11
```

can i do the same just with pure regex?

thanks!

Comment: You can use `str.match(/:\s*(\d+)$/)[1]`.

Comment: sometimes the string is just "bar: 11", so i want to avoid to use [1]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using negative regex you can use this regex:

```
/\d+(?![^:]*:)/g
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/iZdpZS/2)

`(?![^:]*:)` is negative lookahead to assert that there is no `:` ahead of digits we are matching.

**Code Demo:**

```js
var myString = 'foo: 21, bar: 11';
console.log(myString.match(/\d+(?![^:]*:)/g));
```

Comment: This solution differs from my approach since it will extract multiple digit chunks that are after the last `:` - see [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/xFNZ0z/1). It will also grab the digits if there is no `:` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/xFNZ0z/2)). I do not know if that is of any importance to OP though.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var myString = 'foo: 21, bar: 11';
console.log(myString.replace(/(.)*\:\s?/,''));
```

Comment: what does this do? replace everything before latest : ?

Comment: yes. (.)* means all. \: -> last column \s? if there is a space, it will be removed. else no action .

Comment: what's the quantified group for, why not just `.*`

Comment: it is also accepted. But if there are large number of conditions, grouping will make it easy to understand

Answer (score 1):

You may use either of the two solutions:

This one will match up to the last `:` and grab the digits after 0+ whitespaces:

```js
var s = "foo: 21, bar: 11";
var m = s.match(/.*:\s*(\d+)/);
if (m !== null) {
  console.log(m[1]);
}
```

And this one will find a `:` followed with 0+  whitespaces, then will capture 1+ digits into Group 1 and then will match 0+ chars other than `:` up to the end of string.

```js
var s = "foo: 21, bar: 11";
m1 = s.match(/:\s*(\d+)[^:]*$/);
if (m1 !== null) {
  console.log(m1[1]);
}
```

Comment: Note that I assume the string always contains at least one `:` and there is only one chunk of digits to capture after it.